# Removing custom meta box added in parent theme

Tags: metabox, child-theme, pluggable

I am using a child theme, and wish to change one of the meta boxes defined in the parent theme.
The meta box is for 'pages' only.
I tried using the remove_meta_box in my functions.php, but it has no effect:

```
function remove_parents_box() {
    remove_meta_box( 'id-of-meta-box' , 'page' , 'normal' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_parents_box' );
```

Any ideas?

**Addition to question:**
I found that the parent theme uses:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'lala_create_meta_box_page' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'lala_save_meta_data_page' );
```

To initiate this meta box.  As I wish to create the meta-box with my own code, should I actually remove it by something like:

```
remove_action( 'admin_menu', 'lala_create_meta_box_page',999 );
```

And then create my own meta-box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: This is the merged version between my and @toscho answers.*

#### Explanation (by @toscho)

Use `add_meta_boxes_page` as action hook.

You can find the hook in `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` and it displays as:

```
do_action('add_meta_boxes_' . $post_type, $post);
```

#### Solution(s)

Try the following action, which is inside `register_post_type()` as well.

```
function wpse59607_remove_meta_box( $callback )
{
    remove_meta_box( 'id-of-meta-box' , 'page' , 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'wpse59607_remove_meta_box', 999 );
```

If you know the exact position where the action, that adds the meta box is registered, you can also just remove this one.

```
function wpse59607_remove_meta_box()
{
    remove_action( 'admin_menu', 'lala_create_meta_box_page' );
}
add_action( '_admin_menu', 'wpse59607_remove_meta_box', 999 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer!
**Note: I have continued my question.**

Comment: The two actions I mentioned are located in a file included from the functions.php.

Comment: What is the problem with the include?

Comment: The include is for the php file with the parent theme's original add_meta_box functions, and the add_action of them which I was trying to remove.
**The problem** is that when using the second solution, which I hoped will remove the whole original action of adding the meta-box in the parent theme, nothing happens.

Comment: Try the updated answer.

Comment: OK - got it all working fine.  What is the essence of the '_' before the action reference?

Comment: That's just the name of an hook, that's running earlier. There's also `adminmenu` - quite confusing. I know.